# Updating w32tex

Tags: updating, distributions

Is there any way to update w32tex? I found that the question on updating TeX distribution has already been posted
[How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution), but there is no answer regarding w32tex.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no smart way, sorry.

Comment: Okay, I understand!